# store data to isolated storage in memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, storage

I have to store data to isolated storage in memory in such a way that other applications
that are run by the same user and at the same time other users running the same application
cannot access the data directly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();
```

But befor to use it you need to import namespace `System.IO.IsolatedStorage;`

 Here is more detail [IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx)